# Ovito dislocation analysis

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, lammps, ovito

How can I append my pipeline in Ovito?
I tried to append DislocationAnalysisModifier with Selected atom:

```py
from ovito.io import import_file 
from ovito.modifiers import SelectTypeModifier, CommonNeighborAnalysisModifier, PolyhedralTemplateMatchingModifier, DislocationAnalysisModifier 
from ovito.data import DislocationNetwork 

pipeline = import_file("./0.dat") 
# Insert a CNA modifier to determine the structural type of each atom: 
pipeline.modifiers.append(PolyhedralTemplateMatchingModifier()) 

# Apply the SelectTypeModifier to select all atoms of FCC and HCP type: pipeline.modifiers.append(SelectTypeModifier(
   operate_on = "particles", 
   property = "Structure Type", 
   types = { PolyhedralTemplateMatchingModifier.Type.FCC,
             PolyhedralTemplateMatchingModifier.Type.HCP } 
   ))
 
# Extract dislocation lines from a crystal with FCC:

pipeline.modifiers.append(DislocationAnalysisModifier( 
      only_selected = True)) 

data = pipeline.compute() 

total_line_length = data.attributes['DislocationAnalysis.total_line_length'] 

cell_volume = data.attributes['DislocationAnalysis.cell_volume'] 

print("Dislocation density: %f" % (total_line_length / cell_volume))
```

And the output was:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "nn.py", line 20, in <module> only_selected = True)) 
AttributeError: Object type DislocationAnalysisModifier does not have an attribute named 'only_selected'. 
ERROR: The Python script 'nn.py' has exited with an error.
```

I just want to know how to append "only_selected" in DislocationAnalysisModifier?

Using `Ovito 3.0.0-dev155`, with `Python 3.9.13`.

Comment: What version of ovito do you have installed? I don't know much about the package, but the line you have seems consistent with the current documentation, so maybe you are using an old version.

Comment: I use Ovito 3.0.0-dev155, with Python 3.9.13

Answer (score 2):

While it seems like other modifiers can accept this argument, from [the ovito python docs](https://www.ovito.org/docs/current/python/modules/ovito_modifiers.html#ovito.modifiers.DislocationAnalysisModifier), it looks like `only_selected` needs to be specified as a property.

Try changing that line to something like:

```
DAM = DislocationAnalysisModifier()
DAM.only_selected = True
pipeline.modifiers.append(DAM)
```